How can I get the current IP address from the local network?
I would like to know the IP address of the ESP32 the program is running on.
How do I do that?

The IP address comes from an opened network.
Say we use the default network (WiFi), then the code is as follows:
import net

main:
  network := net.open
  print network.address
  network.close

